# Boost program options seems to fail

Tags: c++, boost

I would absolutely love to USE C++ TO DO SOMETHING, however, I have just worked for several hours on a `boost::program_options` interface only to find that even by copying and pasting the tutorial code available on boost's web page, the interface fails to yield the command line strings with a `boost::any_cast` categorically catastrophic failure.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include<boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp>
#include<boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

namespace alg = boost::algorithm;
namespace po = boost::program_options;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char ** argv){
  int opt;
  po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
  desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
    ("optimization", po::value<int>(&opt)->default_value(10),
     "optimization level")
    ("include-path,I", po::value< vector<string> >(),
     "include path")
    ("input-file", po::value< vector<string> >(), "input file")
    ;
  po::positional_options_description p;
  p.add("input-file", -1);

  po::variables_map vm;
  po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).
    options(desc).positional(p).run(), vm);
  po::notify(vm);
  if (vm.count("include-path"))
  {
    cout << "Include paths are: ";
    for (auto i : vm["include-path"].as< vector<string> >())
         cout << i << "\n";
  }

  if (vm.count("input-file"))
  {
    cout << "Input files are: ";
    for (auto i : vm["include-path"].as<vector<string>>())
      cout << i << "\n";
  }

  cout << "Optimization level is " << opt << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

This fails to output any args for anything other than `--help`.  How does one pluck this data out of the boost `variables_map`?

Comment: I can't see any use of `boost::any` in your code? Please provide a [mre] with your expected and actual behaviour and output

Comment: @AlanBirtles this is in the `.as<...>` cast.  Have you tried executing it?

Comment: @AlanBirtles the reason I ask is because I am running off of a cygwin install. Perhaps it is environment specific.

Comment: You have a typo: in the conditional starting `if (vm.count("input-file"))` you attempt to reference `vm["include-path"]` rather than `vm["input-file"]`.  Once that's fixed the code shown appears to work as I would expect (linux + boost 1,71,0).

Comment: @G.M. damn that was too many hours staring at a screen. Alright, I'll give it a shot.